# How exactly does Android debugging work and why does my app behave differently when debugging it?

Tags: android, performance, debugging, dalvik

I have an app that decodes an incoming H264 video stream. When I use the app normally, I get visual artifacts when viewing the stream.

The strange thing is, as soon as I start debugging the process, the artifacts disappear! And when I stop debugging (i.e. unplugging the device from the PC) the artifacts reappear again.

That's why I want to know from you experts: **How does debugging on Android work and in what way does it change a process' behaviour?**

Comment: read this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDebugging/article.html

Comment: This looks like sync error.

Comment: @nitin I'm sorry but this gets me nowhere. I don't want to know how to use debugging, I want to know why and how debugging changes the behaviour of apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using the Java-language debugger, and not a native debugger like gdb.

When you attach a debugger, Dalvik stops executing JIT-compiled code and runs everything in the interpreter.  It uses a less-efficient version of the interpreter that has some extra debugger support, so if you (say) "step over" a method call, and the method throws an exception, you stop.  (If all it did was set a temporary breakpoint on the following instruction, you'd never hit it.)

The "debug interpreter" and the regular "portable" interpreter are built from substantially the same source code -- it's the same source files, built twice, with different macro definitions -- so differences in behavior are usually about performance rather than execution.

The JIT compiler generates and executes code natively, so it's quite a bit different.  Like the interpreter, it hasn't changed much over the last few years, except for the occasional [OEM modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891086/understanding-android-tight-loops-spin-on-suspend-error/18945677#18945677), and is unlikely to be the cause of problems.

The most significant difference between debug and non-debug is performance.  Anything with a race condition will behave differently, because you're going from a fast interpreter with JIT-compiled native code to a slower interpreter.  Without knowing the structure of your code it's impossible to say if this is the issue, but you can find an overview of [SMP on Android here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/smp.html).